# Python: replace &quote; to \"

Tags: python, replace

I have a string like

```
This was really &quote;awesome&quote; isn't it?
```

And i need to convert the text to this format

```
This was really \"awesome\" isn't it?
```

I tried to use `replace("&quote;", "\"")` but I got this one:

```
This was really "awesome" isn\'t it?
```

Which is not exactly what I am trying to get.

Any idea?

Comment: You cannot have two double quotes next to each other. Try single quotes. I would also do the replace with regex, using the import re module.

Comment: @StefanGruenwald Not true... `"\""` is valid and is equivalent to `'"'`.

Comment: Your result is actually exactly what you want, you just don't realize it. The IDE is displaying the string with single quotes around it, so the double quotes don't need escaping.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think the OP actually *wants* a backslash in front of the double quotes.

Comment: yes, but you need the r for raw in front of it. I tried it, and I get this: This was really \"awesome\" isn't it? Here is what I did... string="This was really &quote;awesome&quote; isn't it?"
print string.replace("&quote;", r"\"")

Comment: Do you really want _just_ `&quote;` to `\"`? Or do you want to unescape HTML character entity references and then backslash-escape quotes (and possibly other special characters)?

Comment: Actually, wait… do you really have `'&quote;'` rather than `'&quot;'`? If so, where did this come from? (Knowing what format you have is always better than guessing at it…)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `replace("&quote;", r'\"')`.  The `r'...'` with the "r" in front of the quotes means make it a "raw" string, so the backslashes are not interpreted as special characters (which is what happened to you in the first case).

Comment: Yes I tried but i got this result - This was really \\"awesome\\" isn\'t it?

Comment: Are you using `print` to show this?  If not, please do.

Comment: @StanislavTeroff it will depend on whether you `print` the result or just let the IDE show the result.